# Increasing GIF animation speed with PHP GD

Tags: php, gd, gif, animated-gif

I got a simple website that has a GIF image from an external source but the GIF animation is too slow so I want to know how I can change the GIF animation speed using PHP GD. I will be setting it to a fixed speed so I won't need to worry about having variable speeds.

Comment: No you can't. From [GD's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php), *When reading animated GIF files into memory, only the first frame is returned in the image resource pointer.*

Comment: Well since I'm using 7.1, is there a way to increase the animation speed in php?

Comment: Still can't . PHP GD library has no such feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it to work by using these two classes.

https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3234-PHP-Split-GIF-animations-into-multiple-images.html
https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3163-PHP-Generate-GIF-animations-from-a-set-of-GIF-images.html

This works by decoding the GIF into separate images and then recombining them into a new GIF at a different animation speed. I'm not sure if this uses GD but it does what I needed it to do without using imagick.